# Which capabilities are available in Gravity Forms Salesforce plugin?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, plugin-gravity-forms

Which capabilities are there in Gravity Forms Salesforce plugin and what do they do?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect question for their support :) Sorry, but third party plugin questions are off topic here.

Comment: @kero Serious question, is there, 'I was looking for an answer but couldn't find it on Stack, so I made a topic so others don't have to search' thing where we can post stuff like this for future reverence, even if its a third-party plugin?

Comment: StackExchange *isn't* the place to go looking for 3rd-party support. Here's what the [help page](/help/on-topic) page has to say about 3rd-party plugins & themes: *As these required detailed knowledge of the workings of those plugins and themes, support is difficult and with thousands of plugins and themes available such knowledge is very specialized. Please consult the appropriate support forum for the plugin or theme in question.*

Comment: @EvertSlagter Feel free to [open a question on meta](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/) to discuss this. My personal opinion: the question is off topic, so I voted to close it. You self-answering a question (before it gets closed) I welcome (and might upvote if I think it is a good answer), for the same reason you stated here. But that doesn't make the question on topic suddenly.

Answer (score 1):

Found the capabilities, most are self explanatory.

```
<?php

array(

  'vxg_salesforce_read_feeds' => true,
  'vxg_salesforce_edit_feeds' => true,
  'vxg_salesforce_read_logs' => true,
  'vxg_salesforce_export_logs' => true,
  'vxg_salesforce_read_settings' => true,
  'vxg_salesforce_edit_settings' => true,
  'vxg_salesforce_send_to_crm' => true,
  'vxg_salesforce_read_license' => true,
  'vxg_salesforce_uninstall' => true,

);

?>
```

Comment: Posted 2 minutes after you also posted the question...

Comment: Yes indeed,... maybe it helps others in the future?

Comment: @vancoder Did something change? [Self answers are encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).